# jQuery .is(':checked') always returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery

No mater if the radio button is checked or not, .is(':checked') will return false.  Here is some stuff I was playing with in Chrome's console while I was debugging this:

```
> $('#blah')
[<input type=​"radio" id=​"blah" name=​"blah_type" value=​"blah" class=​"styled" checked=​"checked">​]
> $('#blah').removeAttr('checked')
[<input type=​"radio" id=​"blah" name=​"blah_type" value=​"blah" class=​"styled">​]
> $('#blah').is(':checked')
false
> $('#blah').prop('checked', true)
[<input type=​"radio" id=​"blah" name=​"blah_type" value=​"blah" class=​"styled">​]
> $('#blah').is(':checked')
false
> $('#blah').prop('checked')
true
> $('#blah').removeProp('checked')
[<input type=​"radio" id=​"blah" name=​"blah_type" value=​"blah" class=​"styled">​]
> $('#blah').attr('checked', true)
[<input type=​"radio" id=​"blah" name=​"blah_type" value=​"blah" class=​"styled" checked=​"checked">​]
> $('#blah').attr('checked')
"checked"
> $('#blah').prop('checked')
undefined
> $('#blah').is(':checked')
false
```

What could be going wrong here?  I'm using jQuery 1.6.4.

Comment: Works fine here with 1.6.4: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wqhVQ/

Comment: @arxanas nothing I can do about that. work requires this version for now.

Comment: What happens if you rewrite it as .attr('checked', true)?

Comment: or maybe `$('#blah').attr('checked', 'checked')`

Comment: Although this behaviour seems inconsistent, and makes for an interesting question, in your _real_ code you should only set the checked status with `.prop('checked', trueOrFalse)`. Don't use `.attr()`, `.removeAttr()` or `.removeProp()`. To test the status use `$('#blah').prop('checked')` when you know the jQuery object has only one element (as when you select by id), or `.is(":checked")` if you want to see if at least one of a larger set of elements is checked.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka I'm not... this is a single element.

Comment: Are you having the same problem when you run some code with your markup without trying to manipulate it via the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the jQuery API docs, do not use `.removeProp()` to remove `checked` or other native properties. I would assume the same for `.removeAttr()` as well.

http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/

Comment: This was it.  I took @nnnnnn advice and checked to see if removeProp was being used and it was.  Changed that to .prop('checked', false) and it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: removeAttr() and removeProp() are not the same thing.. before prop came out removeAttr was the right way to handle changes..  Remove prop should actually never be used

Answer (score 5):

use `.prop('checked')`.

I too faced the same problem. `.is()` is not able to catch the checked status for a check box element.